# My very simple custom Puppet type and provider does not work

Tags: ruby, puppet

I am reading about how to create custom types and providers in Puppet. 
But I am getting the error:

```
Error: Could not autoload puppet/provider/createfile/ruby: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

when running the below code:

mymodule/lib/puppet/type/filecreate.rb

```
require 'fileutils'

Puppet::Type.newtype(:filecreate) do
  ensurable do
    defaultvalues
    defaultto :present
  end

  @doc = "Create a file."

  newproperty(:name, :namevar => true) do
    desc "The name of the file"
  end

  newproperty(:path) do
    desc "The path of the file"
  end
end
```

mymodule/lib/puppet/provider/filecreate/ruby.rb

```
require 'fileutils'

Puppet::Type.type(:filecreate).provide(:ruby) do
  desc "create file.."

  puts resource[:name]  # this line does not seem to work, why?
  puts resource[:path]  # this line does not seem to work, why?

  def create
    puts "create file..."
    puts resource[:name]
  end

 def destroy
    puts ("destroy file...")
    FileUtils.rm resource[:path]+resource[:name]
  end

  # Exit method never seems to be called
  def exists?
    puts "is method beeing called???"
    File.exists?(resource[:path])
  end
end
```

I guess the way of fetching the parameter values, `puts resource[:name]` not is correct. So how can I fetch the filename `file.txt` declared as the namevar for my custom type `filecreate` (see below)?

Also, method `exists` does not seem to be called. Why?

And my init.pp contains this simple code:

```
class myclass {
  filecreate{'file.txt':
    ensure => present,
    path   => '/home/myuser/',
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `puts` calls do not work because you try and access an instance attribute (`resource`) on the class level. It makes no semantic sense to access the values in this context. Remove those calls.

Generally, it is better to use `Puppet.debug` instead of `puts` to collect this kind of information.

To find out where such errors come from, call `puppet` with the `--trace` option.

Comment: Thanks for you input! I removed the `puts` but the my Puppet installation seemed to be corrupted, so I reinstalled the whole thing and now it works. :)